# EF6 and business logic layer

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to get a grasp of using the EF for an upcoming project.

Currently I have this code first code:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

This created the database and tables and I've been able to add blogs / post no problem. But I am confused about how to structure around EF code first approach.

Should both `Blog` and `Post` have a reference to `BloggingContext` and then have their own get / add / update methods ?

Should I create separate `BlogManager` / `PostManager` classes that actually do the getting / adding / updating of data and simply return the entity objects?

Should I create separate classes that inherit from `Blog` / `Post` that contain the get / add / update methods?

Comment: I think you should do nothing as all you need is in place in your code example. The DbSet in your DbContext has mechanisms to track your entities. When you would call `dbContext.SaveChanges()` all tracked changes will go to the Datebase

Comment: You typically want to create `IBlogRepository` and `IPostRepository` interfaces and corresponding implementations that wrap your `BloggingContext`. That way you can abstract the actual implementation and usage of ORM from your business logic classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should both Blog and Post have a reference to `BloggingContext`

No - the classes themselves should not be tied to a particular source.  They should just represent an entity and be independent of where the data comes from. That allows for easier unit testing since you can create a blog that is completely independent of your data source.

> Should I create separate BlogManager / PostManager classes that actually do the getting / adding / updating of data and simply return the entity objects?

Yes - this is typically called a *repository*, so `BlogRepository` and `PostRepository` might be better names.

Since the two will be inter-dependent it would also be good to create `IBLogRepository` and `IPostRepository` interfaces that the repositories implement so you don't tightly couple the repositories.  Then when you query for a blog and want it's post as well the `BlogRepository` can chain the request to the `IPostRepository`.

> Should I create separate classes that inherit from Blog / Post that contain the get / add / update methods?

No - because inheritance implies an "is a" relationship - and a class that *saves* a blog it not necessarily a blog itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your last point has really made me think about how I structure my applications. Normally I would probably have put everything that is to do with `Blog` into a single `Blog` class.  e.g. If I had a UI function (e.g. return data formatted for UI use), that would go in `Blog`, if I had a function to delete all Blogs with no posts, that would go in `Blog` too. Should things like "Delete all blogs with no posts" go into `BlogRepository`  then a separate `BlogUI`class for the UI functions?

Comment: Yes - ideally classes should have one function:  carry data, store data, do calculations, display data, etc are all different functions.  Otherwise you end up with gargantuan classes that are difficult to change, debug, test, mock, etc.

Comment: Sent me pretty far down the rabbit hole, spent that last 22 hours reading up on SOLID principles. At first it seemed really ANTI-OBJECT from what I thought an object should be. But I see now used right and where needed does make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

The `DbContext` class can handle everything data-related on its own. You don't need to include a reference to them in your entity classes (nor should you, since `DbContext` classes open up a database connection). `DbContext` will also handle your basic CRUD operations on its own (through the use of the `DbSets<T>` on it, which are easy ways to access all of the data in a specific table.

If you want, you could also do what @Sergey mentioned above in the comments and implement a repository interface on top of it. I have written a blog post about doing that which you can [find here](http://www.paragon-inc.com/resources/blogs-posts/the-repo-man). Basically, you set it up as a generic repository with a background reference to the `DbContext` class, and in that way you can put up a nice layer in between your application code and your database logic.

Comment: The URL seems down, @IronMan84.

Comment: Weird. Always happens to me on VPN. Please try it now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't think my question was very well phrased. My "normal" way to code would be to have a `Blog` class which does most things Blog related e.g. `var blog = new Blog(1)` would try to load blog id 1 from the database, then I can change properties and call functions to manipulate that `Blog` then call `blog.Save() (uses TableAdapters)` to save it back to the DB. Should I be using EF / DBContext as a replacement for table adapters? Or can they become my `Blog` class? ps, reading through your blog!